# How to get entire function list of ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to get a list of functions hit by an ASP.NET page?  The only way I can think of is to put a breakpoint in the Page_Load and hit F11 over and over.  I am debugging a slow page_load this is why I ask.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote neither the close vote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[page Load is too late you should start at page constructor or at least at page PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

did you try a profiler like [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/walkthrough) or the [Performance Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx) or simply loking at the [asp.net Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called profiling. Google search for [asp.net profiler](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=asp.net%20profiler&oq=asp.net%20profiler) and choose one. Also [asp.net trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) give information about method call times.

There are built-in solutions for asp.net [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx) and [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255401.aspx) also [commercial ones](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/walkthrough).